# Cordova app - "<Warning>" when navigating pages

Tags: xcode, cordova, xcode5

I'm inspecting a fairly simple (no hardware interfacing) Cordova app in the device organiser in Xcode. The app consists of a few separate HTML pages. I'm trying to rule out memory issues with this app.

Each time I navigate to a separate HTML page I get a warning like the below...

```
Jul 15 14:12:52 My-iPad PMShell[2069] <Warning>: file:///var/mobile/Applications/40D5E135-C866-4590-B97F-51C71CED083C/PMShell.app/Content/page2.html#
```

I'd like to rule this out as being a problem if possible - could anyone elaborate what the warning pertains to? Or is is just for information? I can't find anything referencing this with a search.

Any advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A separate build via a different tool showed that this warning only serves to tell the console that you've moved to a different HTML page inside your app.